# React native image have bad quality

Tags: react-native

I used hd image but my image have bad quality (large and pixelated) whit this code:

```
<Image source={require('../../assets/images/logo.png')}/>
```

When i `resizeMode: 'center'` the quality is good, but image is small.

```
<Image style={{resizeMode: 'center'}}
  source={require('../../assets/images/logo.png')}/>
```

My actual image size is:
**153px** x **43px**

Answer (score 1):

You know the dimensions of the image. So set `style={{ resizeMode:'stretch', width:XXXX, height:XXXX }}` where width and height maintain aspect ratio. Using stretch has the added benefit of the image's `View` container being perfectly fit to it, so you can position the element perfectly.